# How come the Eye of Agamotto worked in the Dark Dimension?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange-2016

It is my understanding that each universe has its own Infinity Stones and they only work within their respective universes.

Dormammu exists within a universe where he controls every bit of energy and matter. He goes from universe to universe to draw more energy into his own.<sup>*</sup>

When he entered into the universe the Doctor Strange movie was in, there was a portal that merged the 2 universes that Strange used to enter the Dark Dimension and confront Dormammu.

Now, the basic assumption here is that the word *dimension* is used synonymously with *universe*.

How come Doctor Strange was able to use an Infinity Stone from his own universe in the Dark Dimension? Likewise, shouldn't Dormammu wield nearly infinite power by possessing the Infinity Stones of his own universe?

---

<sup>*</sup> Overlooking the fact that I am sure he tried to invade a particular universe and, unbeknownst to him, he was met with an alternate version of himself, only nicer, friendlier, and had a penchant for showtunes.

Comment: Well, dimensions were bleeding together at that point.  They're not supposed to do that.  Rules?  What rules?

Comment: *It is my understanding that each universe has its own Infinity Stones and they only work within their respective universes.* Maybe in the comics, but this isn't the comics.

Comment: @phantom42 What do you think the movies are based on? Did they just make up the character, abilities, and all the constituents that typify a Doctor Strange story? No. They sourced from the original material and other Marvel franchises and kept with certain *de facto* premises to allow for lateral transitions and future convergences. The same fundamental concept is iterated in other Marvel movies.

Comment: @Radhil The overarching theme of superhero movies is predicated on a set of rules that diverge from our own reality. That status quo is established in each universe/story. The question is stated within the context of the 2016 movie.

Comment: "It is my understanding that each universe has its own Infinity Stones and they only work within their respective universes." What specifically leads you to believe that?

Comment: Yes, they largely based things on the comics - but they are not beholden to the comics either. Lots of things have changed - backstories, rules, forms, identities... This *might* be one of those things that have been altered or straight up ignored.

Comment: to be pedantic, there is only one set of Infinity Stones. The ones in the comics are Infinity _Gems_.

Comment: “They... kept with certain *de facto* premises to allow for lateral transitions and future convergences.” In an infinite multiverse there’s probably a universe where that sentence means something, but here, Marvel hasn’t said a thing about different universes having their own Infinity Stones in the MCU.

Comment: I don't think you can assume weird dimensions have infinity stones.  The stones are related to the big bang of our reality.   I wouldn't expect Steve Ditko Dark Dimensions to have such simple well behaved rules of physics as our mere big bang spawned reality

Answer (score 7):

I believe within the context, that the *Dark Dimension* is part of the same universe in question. As shown in the film Doctor Strange, when he is travelling through the dimensions/universes, guided by the Ancient One that he is still within his own larger universe or multiverse (rather that being a smaller multiverse within the Marvel multiverse that the Sorcerers cannot break through). Or perhaps the Infinity Stone, regardless of whether in was within its dimension of origin acted as a battery and outlet. The Stone of Agamotto serving as a battery storing or rather generating time. Making Dormammu unable to control the foreign energy from his universe.

Secondly, as I am not terribly familiar with Marvel functions please forgive me if I'm wrong; but there may be no Infinity stones within his dimension. And if each universe has its own set of Stones then the *Dark Dimension* may not be a universe independent of itself.

Answer (score 2):

> they only work within their respective universes

As we have now seen in *What If...?*, this is not the case for the MCU.

> Ultron was able to use the power of his Infinity Stones in every universe he invaded

> the word dimension is used synonymously with universe.

Likewise it's heavily implied that every universe has its own Dark Dimension

> Dr Strange consumes every extra-dimensional being in his own universe, which doesn't appear to effect any other universes

Answer (score 1):

> Now, the basic assumption here is that the word dimension is used synonymously with universe.

This is the crux of your confusion, because it's an incorrect assumption. A given universe is made up of many dimensions, some known and some unknown to us (for our universe).

The dark dimension is wholly part of this universe, it is just a 'layer' of our universe that most cannot perceive/access. Same with the mirror dimension, etc. Think of the Tesseract for example. A tesseract is literally a 4-dimensional cube, but we traditionally have only perceived of 3 dimensions in our universe (X, Y, and Z, if you will)... sometimes folks will consider "time" the 4th dimension.

Likewise, the infinity stones are all specific to our universe; the timelines created in Avengers: Endgame are all still part of the Earth-199999 universe. We haven't seen anything to do with alternate universes except in *Spider-man: Far From Home* where Nick Fury and Mysterio allude to Peter Parker that they're a thing:

Granted, that is technically just Mysterio lying, since he is actually from Earth-199999... but if Peter Parker, an Avenger who participated in the Battle of Earth in Endgame and knows Doctor Strange, is surprised to hear about alternate universes, then it stands to reason that nothing Doctor Strange or the Avengers had done to date would have dealt with alternate universes.

Out of universe, I expect we'll learn more about alternate universes in 2022 when *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* comes out.

Answer (score -2):

Marvel has very different definitions of :

- Reality
- Dimension
- Universe

For some reason. I think you're just confused.

For example there are actually LOTS of Marvel character that have reality controling/shifting powers and if you're not familiar with the difference you'd think "oh he's over-powered" but not really.

Comment: I'm unsure as to how this answer the question asked, please consider [edit]ing the answer to address the question.

Answer (score -2):

I think the confusion lies with the assumption that a universe and a dimension are the same thing. Dormammu’s home the Dark Dimension connects to the entirety of the multi-verse. Infinity stones don’t exist in the Dark Dimension because the stones are a universal power confined to the sole universe, with that being said the Time Stone worked because Strange used it on himself somebody who exists in the same universe as that stone, the Dark Dimension wasn’t affected just strange.

Comment: Can you provide any citations from films, comics or snippets of speech that support your answer. You come to a logical conclusion but some evidence from the source material would boost your answer!

Answer (score -4):

Well I believe dark dimension, quantum realm , astral realm and all known dimensions within MCU are part of a very big universe, and since its within the same unierse, time stone worked against dormammu. So technically Dark Dimension is part of the same big universe. I am sorry if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the SF&F Stack Exchange. Unfortunately this isn't a very good answer in the context of this site. Without any links or other supporting material to back up your claim, it's just an opinion. To be considered a good answer, you'll need to provide some evidence for your claim. You can check out the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information on answering questions.